# Comparing powers and factorials

Tags: number-theory, binomial-theorem

Let $a_n = \frac {1000^n}{n!}$ for $n \in N$. Then $a_n$ is greatest for:-

(A) $n=998$   (B) $n=999$ (C) $n=1000$ (D) $n=1001$

How to approach? Need hints.

Comment: A? $n=998$? is the answer?

Comment: Try it, by calculation, for $\frac{3^n}{n!}$ instead

Comment: @TheDeadLegend, I don't know, sorry. But please give me some hints.

Comment: Hint: $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{1000^{n+1}/(n+1)!}{1000^n/n!}  = \frac{1000}{n+1}$. Provided that this ratio is $>1$, you will have $a_{n+1}>a_n$. If this ratio is $=1$, then $a_{n+1}=a_n$, and if this ratio is $<1$ then $a_{n+1}<a_n$.

Comment: @kccu . So $n=1000$ and $n=999$ should be the answers, right? Nice method though. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I believe so.

Comment: Which means it is not a good question unless multiple answers are allowed.  There is not a single correct answer.

Comment: @RossMillikan. The question is supposed to be multiple correct answer type. In India, these type of questions come in IIT-JEE examination.

Answer (score 1):

In general the maximum value is between $n$ and $n-1$.

$sup(\frac{c^n}{n!})$ and using Stirling approximation $n! \approx n^n e^{-n} \sqrt{2 \pi n}$.

Which is approximately $sup(\frac{c^n}{n^n e^{-n} \sqrt{2 \pi n}})$ , the maximum value is when $(\frac{c^n}{n^n e^{-n} \sqrt{2 \pi n}})' =0$, we reach at $\frac{e^n n^{-n-\frac{1}{2}} c^n}{\sqrt{2 \pi }}+\frac{e^n n^{-n-\frac{1}{2}} c^n
   \log (c)}{\sqrt{2 \pi }}+\frac{e^n n^{-n-\frac{1}{2}} c^n
   \left(\frac{-n-\frac{1}{2}}{n}-\log (n)\right)}{\sqrt{2 \pi }}=0$ with a little bit of manipulation we arrive at $\log (c)-\frac{1}{2 n}-\log (n)=0$,which gives the answer $n=-\frac{1}{2 W\left(-\frac{1}{2 c}\right)}$, which can be easily bounded between $n$ and $n-1$.